# (Pandas) Different way of combining two dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, python-datetime

I was wandering if theres a better approach of combining two dataframes than what I did below.

```
import pandas as pd

#create ramdom data sets
N = 50
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': pd.date_range('2000-1-1', periods=N, freq='H'),
 'value': np.random.random(N)})

index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['date'])
peak_time = df.iloc[index.indexer_between_time('7:00','9:00')]
lunch_time = df.iloc[index.indexer_between_time('12:00','14:00')]

comb_data = pd.concat([peak_time, lunch_time], ignore_index=True)
```

Is there a way to combine two ranges when using between_time using logical operator?

I have to use that to make a new column in df called 'isPeak' where 1 is written when it's in range between  7:00 ~ 9:00 and also 12:00 ~ 14:00 and 0 if not.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For me working [`np.union1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.union1d.html):

```
import numpy as np

idx = np.union1d(index.indexer_between_time('7:00','9:00'), 
                 index.indexer_between_time('12:00','14:00'))

comb_data = df.iloc[idx]
print (comb_data)
                  date     value
7  2000-01-01 07:00:00  0.760627
8  2000-01-01 08:00:00  0.236474
9  2000-01-01 09:00:00  0.626146
12 2000-01-01 12:00:00  0.625335
13 2000-01-01 13:00:00  0.793105
14 2000-01-01 14:00:00  0.706873
31 2000-01-02 07:00:00  0.113688
32 2000-01-02 08:00:00  0.035565
33 2000-01-02 09:00:00  0.230603
36 2000-01-02 12:00:00  0.423155
37 2000-01-02 13:00:00  0.947584
38 2000-01-02 14:00:00  0.226181
```

Alternative with [`numpy.r_`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html):

```
idx = np.r_[index.indexer_between_time('7:00','9:00'), 
            index.indexer_between_time('12:00','14:00')]

comb_data = df.iloc[idx]
print (comb_data)
                  date     value
7  2000-01-01 07:00:00  0.760627
8  2000-01-01 08:00:00  0.236474
9  2000-01-01 09:00:00  0.626146
31 2000-01-02 07:00:00  0.113688
32 2000-01-02 08:00:00  0.035565
33 2000-01-02 09:00:00  0.230603
12 2000-01-01 12:00:00  0.625335
13 2000-01-01 13:00:00  0.793105
14 2000-01-01 14:00:00  0.706873
36 2000-01-02 12:00:00  0.423155
37 2000-01-02 13:00:00  0.947584
38 2000-01-02 14:00:00  0.226181
```

Pure pandas solution with [`Index.union`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.union.html) and convert array to `index`:

```
idx = (pd.Index(index.indexer_between_time('7:00','9:00'))
         .union(pd.Index(index.indexer_between_time('12:00','14:00'))))

comb_data = df.iloc[idx]
print (comb_data)
                  date     value
7  2000-01-01 07:00:00  0.760627
8  2000-01-01 08:00:00  0.236474
9  2000-01-01 09:00:00  0.626146
12 2000-01-01 12:00:00  0.625335
13 2000-01-01 13:00:00  0.793105
14 2000-01-01 14:00:00  0.706873
31 2000-01-02 07:00:00  0.113688
32 2000-01-02 08:00:00  0.035565
33 2000-01-02 09:00:00  0.230603
36 2000-01-02 12:00:00  0.423155
37 2000-01-02 13:00:00  0.947584
38 2000-01-02 14:00:00  0.226181
```

Comment: if we can't use numpy, the thing I did above should be okay?

Comment: If use pandas, change `np.union1d` to `pd.np.union1d`, if problem with `np`. Because pandas is built on numpy :) And for your question - yes, it is correct solution.

Comment: @SeoiMin - Added pure pandas version.